# Why should we use "is" here instead of "are"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, vocabulary, british-english

I was watching an Instagram video posted by Woody and Kleiny account https://www.instagram.com/p/BqxY4lflIKQ/ and here is a sequence of it:

A: Knock-Knock

B: Who is it?

A: It's the Police

B: What do you want?

A: We just want to talk.

B: How many of you **are** there?

A: There **is** two Sir.

B: Talk to each other then.

**Question**: Why it is right to say there is two, instead of there are two?

**Update**: I didn't recall it had subtitles. Know I am seeing that was *there's*.

Comment: It's a mistake usually made by uneducated people. The cop should have said 'there are two'.

Comment: Did A say "There **is** two" or "**There's** two"?

Comment: Did you transcribe this yourself? "Knock-knock" would be the standard spelling.

Comment: I object strongly to the words _mistake_ and (especially) _uneducated_.. When people have a non-standard form in their normal speech, it is not a "mistake", and there are no reasonable grounds for concluding that they are "uneducated".

Comment: Please ***[edit]*** and tell us exactly which film.  It is very bad to quote from a source and not to say what the source is.  If you can link to the script that is even better.  But you  ***must*** at least cite your source

Comment: @JamesK it's an Instagram video posted by Woody and Kleiny account. Right now, I don't have access to its link or the post itself.

Comment: @sumelic I don't recall. Are they different?

Comment: I've done what I said you should do, and **edited** to put the source and the link into your question.  It is clear that this is not a "short British Film" but a very short sketch, self published on the internet.   You also cut out the "punchline" which would have made it clear that this was a joke (and an old joke too)

Comment: @JamesK I don't know why you think it was necessary to add the punchline so that everybody knows it's a joke! I just wanted to know the reason we have a there's and not a there are.

Comment: I added it to give context.  If  these were "real" police, or actors pretending to be real police they wouldn't talk like this. The way they talk is meant to be funny.  I'm trying to make your question better.

Comment: As @ColinFine stated, there's is non-standard here; but quite common. Even a real police can talk in common speech.

Comment: However, thank you for your edit

Comment: I personally would ay "there are two."  My first (mis)interpretation was that the resident upon hearing "there is two" assumed they weren't real police and uttered the last line in preference to letting them in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For many people *there's* is an invariable form, irresepective of whether it is introducing a singular or plural noun phrase.

*There is* is less common in this context, but you sometimes hear it.

It is non-standard, but quite common.

Comment: Dollars to doughnuts, the OP heard "there's" and mistakenly (but understandably) interpreted and transcribed it as 'there is'.

Comment: @fred2: I agree that is likely.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a "knock, knock" joke, one of a large class.  The one you've quoted doesn't seem very funny, but maybe you haven't quoted the entire conversation. As Michael Harvey said in his comment, "There is two" is uneducated usage.

Comment: I doubt very much that it's a knock-knock joke, though the "police" characters are probably riffing on the idea of a knock-knock joke.

Comment: So, a joke about jokes? Without more of the context, it's hard to tell.

Comment: I don't think it's a joke at all. It sounds to me like a serious visit, where the speaker chose a flippant opening line ("Knock knock") to break the ice.

Comment: It's a joke. The punchline is "talk to each other then."  (sad trombone)

Comment: Yes, it is, @JamesK. But it's not a "knock knock" joke.